# Rails find_by option syntax for last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

It's probably unrelated to the issue, but for context I'm using the devise_invitable gem in my app. I've started to modify the invitations_controller.rb as I want to save additional associations between the `invited_user` and other models in my app.

I think the root of my issue is that an `inviting_user` can invite multiple other users and each of these associations is saved in the User model with a field called `invited_by_id`

Before making the additional desired associations between the `invited_user` and my other models, I retrieve the invited_user's `id` with the following:

```
@invited_user = User.find_by_invited_by_id(current_inviter)
```

This does successfully retrieve a record from the User table, but it appears to be the *first* user invited by the `current_inviter`.

I'd like to change the logic so it retrieves the *last* user invited by the `current_inviter`. As such, I tried:

```
@invited_user = User.find_by_invited_by_id(:last, current_inviter)
```

But unfortunately that returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 1:Fixnum
```

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following (Rails 3):

```
User.where(invited_by_id: current_inviter).last
```

Or use the old syntax (Rails 2):

```
User.find(:last, :conditions => ['invited_by_id = ?', current_inviter])
```

Comment: Nice! I noticed adding `.last` will add `DESC LIMIT 1` to the SQL query.